# Can this bamboo with brown leaves recover?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, bamboo

I have a bamboo, phyllostachus aurea (outside over winter, London, UK, 2nd floor balcony, exposed to some wind) that over the winter developed brown leaves. Is this normal? I don't think it's lack of water as it's been watered regularly (every week).

It has some brown spots on some of the leaves.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How  long has it been in the same container? What size is the pot, is it quite deep, say 12 or more inches? I'm assuming there are holes for drainage...